# Problems in Android SDK and AVD Manager on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7

I am trying to install Android SDK - but the Android SDK and AVD Manager seems unable to download addons_list.xml and repository.xml. I have checked "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http:// ..." but that does not help. The error message says that there is the connection has timed out, so changing setting was a long shot.

I can download these xml files using IE and I can save them as files. I don't know if this would help, if I knew where to park these files.

Actual error messages are:

> Failed to fetch https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason:
> Connection timed out: connect
>
> Failed to fetch https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason:
> Connection timed out: connect

FWIW, I am running Android SDK Updater Revision 13.

Thanks,

Comment: I *think* you created a new tag "andriod" (notice the spelling) not on purpose. If you can delete it and replace with "Android", please do. I'm not sure how to delete a newly created tag.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Oops. Oddly enough, "andriod" had 11 followers but wasn't in use for any posts. I suspect (hope) that I wasn't the one who created it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a firewall running?

Is your android-sdk or eclipse folder located in your program files? Are your security notifications set to low? What version of Eclipse are you using? Have you updated Eclipse before updating your SDKs?

When was the last time you updated your android sdk?

Comment: I am not running a firewall locally but I am accessing network via VPN. So, this does seem like a potential problem. I was able to manually download the files, so this leaves me wondering what is different with the Manager app. I am attempting to install Android SDK for the first time. I had Helios and have since installed Indigo - I have had same problem with each. Thanks.

Comment: I just went over to my personal (non-VPN) Mac - and everything just worked. So, this looks like a VPN issue. I will test that theory on Monday.